# Why is a null record cause an entire row to be null when using UNION ALL on MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

The schema looks like,

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
    `id` INT,
    `countryCode` VARCHAR(50),
    `state` VARCHAR(50)
)  ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8MB4 COLLATE = UTF8MB4_0900_AI_CI;
```

Data looks like,

```
insert into `test` values 
(1,'AE','AE'),
(2,'SA','SA'),
(3,NULL,'SA') ;
```

We are using the below query to generate data that will eventually be dumped to a data file

```
SELECT ('id|countryCode|state|') AS `line` 
UNION ALL SELECT 
    CONCAT(CONCAT(`id`, '|'),
            CONCAT(`countryCode`, '|'),
            CONCAT(`state`, '|')) AS `line`
FROM
    `test`;
```

So the issue here is that should a record be null, which in this case id 3 has countrycode as null, the query considers the row as null.
Current ouput is,

```
id|countryCode|state|
1|AE|AE|
2|SA|SA|
*null*
```

What should i do so that the query does return the data it finds instead of the entire row coming as null.

The desired output is,

```
id|countryCode|state|
1|AE|AE|
2|SA|SA|
3||SA
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c413174265e74650cff2227b41767d96)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) returns `NULL` if any of its arguments is `NULL`.
I would suggest that you use [`CONCAT_WS()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) instead with `COALESCE()` for the columns that may be `NULL`:

```
SELECT 'id|countryCode|state|' AS `line` 
UNION ALL 
SELECT CONCAT_WS('|', `id`, COALESCE(`countryCode`, ''), COALESCE(`state`, '')) AS `line`
FROM `test`;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8d80978d29360bacf7e01d9d95a0ba26).

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I know is that you insert a CASE or IF for each column
e.G.

```
SELECT ('id|countryCode|state|') AS `line` 
UNION ALL SELECT 
CONCAT(CONCAT(CASE WHEN `id`IS NULL THEN '' ELSE `id` END , '|'),
        CONCAT(CASE WHEN `countryCode` IS NULL THEN '' ELSE `countryCode` END, '|'),
        CONCAT(CASE WHEN `state` IS NULL THEN '' ELSE `state` END, '|')) AS `line` 
FROM
    `test`;
```

Comment: Thank you! I assume the *THEN '' * is not an empty space, the record returned for that field can be a null btw